# Why authorization doesn't work and there is no access to the page?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, postman

[Link](https://github.com/Blacit/HomeRent/tree/master/src/main/java/task/homerent) my code. Through Postman, I make a request for user registration, it appears in the database, everything is fine, then in the special tab "Authorization" I enter in Postman, select `Basic auth`, enter the data (user name and password), for example, the user name : petya@mail.ru and password: petya Make a request to: `http://localhost:8080/landlord/1` You need to change the role from `TENANT` to `LANDLORD`. But I get an error in Postman and nothing changes in the database. I understand that authorization does not work, maybe I wrote something wrong in the SecurityConfig file?

```
<html lang = "en">

<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title> Login Customer </title>
</head>

<body>
<div class = "container">
<form class = "form-signin" method = "post" action = "/ auth / login">
<h2 class = "form-signin-heading"> Login </h2>
<p>
<label for = "username"> Username </label>
<input type = "text" id = "username" name = "username" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Username" required>
        </p>
<p>
<label for = "password"> Password </label>
<input type = "password" id = "password" name = "password" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Password" required>
        </p>
<button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type = "submit"> Sign in </button>
</form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(@Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                /** На какие страницы человек имеет доступы */
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/auth/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/auth/success")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/logout", "POST"))
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Bean
    protected DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I don't have such a possibility, or rather it is not implemented, I don't know if it is possible to create such a thing or not. But I suspect it's real.

Initially, choose whether you want to create with or without a front, if without, then you only need Rest controllers(I started doing this) and you can get authorization from [this](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/488418/) and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/manually-set-user-authentication-spring-security) links. Next, in Postman, make a Post request with the body - this will be your authorization. **!ATTENTION!** Be sure to read the articles on the links that I attached above, they tell you everything in detail, I do not have the full version of the code here, only the one that may have questions. Also read the comments that are written there, especially on the English-language site, there is an answer to the question about where to get the "authenticationManager". I say right away, its method must be registered in the SecurityConfig class.

I hope that my answer will help someone and save their nerves.

Code of what the new method for authorization looks like now:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public String getLoginPage(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        userService.loginUser(userDto);
        return "login";
    }
```

You can notice that I accept UserDto, in it I have:

```
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String first_name;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String last_name;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String password;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String email;
```

And here is the authorization check itself:

```
public void loginUser(UserDto accountDto) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq
            = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(accountDto.getEmail(), accountDto.getPassword());
    Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authReq);
    SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    sc.setAuthentication(auth);
}
```